# How to merge data from different sources with a condition in GSheet?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gsheets

I am trying to merge data from different GSheet sources while filtering them to get only cases that are >= 30min in a processing time column. However, before even filtering it, I'm facing a problem just importing the data.

I using a code like:

```
=query({
    importrange("url1", "sheet_name!A1:R20000"); 
    importrange("url2", "sheet_name!A2:R20000"); 
    importrange("url3", "sheet_name!A2:R20000"); 
    importrange("url4", "sheet_name!A1:R20000")  
   },                                           
 "select Col 15, Col3, Col2, Col7, Col11, Col12, Col1, Col9 where 
Col1 is not null", 
    1)
```

Just explaining: I have the same columns in all the sources, so I just need the first one with headers and stack the others

By doing so, I get an error message like "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col15. Does anyone know what I am missing?

Also, I would like to include a condition to get only data for cases with processing time greater than 30 min (currently Col9). In the past, I used a code like:

```
=query({sheet_name!A2:Q, arrayformula(if(sheet_name!A2:A="","", 
              if(sheet_name!J2:J-sheet_name!I2:I>time(0,30,0), 
              sheet_name!B2:B&" | "sheet_name!C2:C,
              ""))), 
    "select blablabla"},1)
```

But I am not sure how to do that in a query with several importrange that are not even working properly :/ Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

I have already checked if Col15 was misspelled like col15 in lowercase, but it wasn't. Also, I've tried to use '' inside of

```
importrange("url1", "sheet_name!A1:R20000"),
```

like

```
importrange("url1", " 'sheet_name'!A1:R20000")
```

I've tried to change Col15 for O but didn't work as well. So, I'm clueless right now

Answer (score 1):

How about space between Col and 15 ?
[image]